# Automatically set entitykey in One-to-One relationship with SQLite-Net extensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

In a Xamarin project using SQLite-Net extensions, I have two entities: Project and ProjectSettings. These entities have a one-to-one relationship.
The Project entity has an auto-increment Id. When I initially save a project, the Id of the Project is automatically set. This is working fine.

```
public class Project
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public ProjectSettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

For the ProjectSettings, I would expect that the ProjectId is the same as the Id in the Project table (ForeignKey).

```
public class ProjectSettings
{
    [PrimaryKey, ForeignKey(typeof(Project))]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

However, the ProjectID in the ProjectSettings table is 0 after persisting the Project. 
I am persisting the project using `database.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(project)`. Project and ProjectSettings both have their Id=0 when calling this method.

As I am quite new to SQLite-Net, I am wondering if I am using the annotations incorrectly or if manual steps are necessary to set the key of the ProjectSettings correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `InsertOrReplace` with an `AutoIncrement` primary key with SQLite.Net. It will always override the object with ID `0`. Either use another insert method, or manually assign the primary key.